# Ruby symbols with methods

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm working with Ruby on Rails and am rather new, but I have an extensive programming background in other languages. Currently right now I have the following code:

```
def self.AVERAGE_COMPUTATIONS
{
  :a => ["(AVG(a) as a"],
  :b => ["(AVG(b) as b"],
  ...
  :z => ["(AVG(z) as z"],
}
```

I've been told this is not the best way of doing this because if something changes, especially with the SQL it's a pain to debug, which makes sense. I was told a better way of doing it is as follows:

```
def self.AVERAGE_COMPUTATIONS
{
  :a => [:avg],
  :b => [:avg],
  ...
  :z => [:avg],
}
```

This makes sense in that I am basically doing the same thing so to put it all in a function. But what confuses me is that I'm using a symbol as a function. I'm not sure if that's even possible. Is it? After doing some research I see that you can use `.send(:avg)` but how do I pass a parameter?

I'm a bit confused so any clarification would be greatly appreciated. If someone could show me what the function header would look like if I use `[:avg]` that would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Parameters can be passed as additional arguments to `.send`. Calling `.send(:avg, "a")` would call the `#avg` method, with `"a"` passed as first parameter.

It isn't clear to me what you are trying to achieve with this method. You could dispense with the Hash entirely if every value is the same, irrespective of key. You would not need to use `.send` at all.

```
def self.AVERAGE_COMPUTATIONS(symbol)
  "(AVG(#{symbol}) as #{symbol}"
end
```

where symbol is the key you would be using for the Hash lookup in your code.

This looks like it should achieve what you are trying to do, without needing a Hash.

Comment: So a through z are all check boxes and if the box is checked then I need to compute the average for the dimension and show it on a table. So I could be computing between 1 and 26 averages.